# Is there any way to automate desktop GUI swing applications using java

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a GUI which is not developed me and have to automate it to avoid some manual steps. Any idea how can we automate desktop GUI using java.
I tried using ATS but i don't see the option to open the GUI from swingdriver.
I can see only options by passing window title or class name as parameter in getswingdriver. Since I dnt develop the code I dnt know the class name. On the other hand I know window title but not sure how to open the GUI first and read the title.
Looking for any ideas..

Comment: For general automation of Windows GUI programs, you can try the free-and-open-source scripting language AutoHotkey: https://www.autohotkey.com/

Answer (score 2):

[JAuto](https://heshiming.github.io/jauto/) is a [JVMTI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html) agent that runs in Java VM and expose UI widget attributes such as class names, screen coordinates. It does so by using JVMTI APIs to iterate through live instances of objects. You talk to JAuto by sending a command to a named pipe. It responds by writing a file. Such a communication mechanism lets you control a Java program via something as basic as [bash scripts](https://heshiming.github.io/jauto/faq.html#how-do-i-call-jauto-in-a-bash-script).

With an input simulator such as [xdotool](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool), you can achieve automation under the Linux X11 settings, even inside a docker container.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of JAuto.